# Set storage space and history per node on master node

Tags: monitoring, netdata

For Netdata we got following setup: a lot of nodes sending their metrics to a central node, where the charts get rendered. Now we start having to many servers and not enought power on the master node. Mostly ram and disk are missing.
Is there a way to configure netdata, so that for example the dev host have a few days of history, while the production servers have a month?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting per machine_guid parameters in the parent's (master) stream.conf.

You could check with various options there, like longer `history` for some machine_guids, or different memory modes.

There's some more information in https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/streaming